# What is the best practice for presenting a modal view and binding events to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, jquery-events

In a very common scenario, I have an HTML page with an "Add" button that opens a modal dialog (through Facebox) and asks the user to select an item from the list that appears in it.

The modal dialog gets its HTML snippet from the server asynchronously. I want this snippet to be reusable in many parts of my application so it shouldn't assume that I am using Facebox to load it. The only thing it should do is to trigger the `item-selected` event whenever the user selects an item in it. But since the snippet is loaded asynchronously, I cannot use `$(document).ready`. That is, I cannot trigger the event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").click(function() {
    $(".items-modal-dialog").trigger("item-selected", this);
  });
});
```

Also, I don't really like using the `items-modal-dialog` class to identify the enclosing DOM element.

I came up with some solutions to this, and I would like to know if there is some superior pattern that I am missing, because I think this is a very common problem.

1. Put the script after all the HTML so I am sure that the snippet DOM is loaded (I think this is a bad practice)
2. Creating a JavaScript function that loads the snippet with Facebox and then binds the events. This way I assume that I am using Facebox and also have to create a function for every type of modal dialog that I create. The only positive side I see in this is that I can create the `items-modal-dialog` DIV programmatically so I don't have to use a class to identify it.
3. Using jQuery live to bind the events.
4. Using an iframe and `$(document).ready`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much jQuery event delegation (which `.live()` is a specific case of)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's live or delegate function would be the best solution in my opinion.